# Xamarin.Forms - How to change the cursor position in the input field?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning to develop cross platform mobile applications using Xamarin.Forms and Visual Studio 2017. Input field Entry has a CursorPosition property in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry). But when I try to use it I get the error "Property not found". What am I doing wrong? thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CursorPosition` property has been introduced in [Xamairn.Forms 3.2](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-3.2/). Prior to that you need to write your own CustomRenderer. Check the version and upgrade accordingly.